# sum values in double level dictionary python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary "celldict" that has elements like these :

```
{1224:{'A': 6, 'B': 4, 'C': 5}, 1225: {'A': 6, 'B': 6, 'C': 5}}
```

I want to count just A+B for each key, and get a result like this :

```
{1224:{'A': 6, 'B': 4, 'C': 5,'AB' : 10}, 1225: {'A': 6, 'B': 6, 'C': 5, 'AB' :12 }}
```

So I did this :

```
a = ["A","B"]

for num in celldict :
    found =0
    sum = 0

    for key in a :
        if key in celldict[num][key]:
            print "ignoring existing key"
        else : 
            print "continuing"
            continue
            sum += celldict[num][key]
            found = 1

    if found == 1 : 
        celldict[num]["AB"] = sum 

print   celldict
```

But it's not working, found always returns 0, I am doing something wrong maybe when I try to check the existence of the key in my dictionnary. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: For 2nd item B is changed from 4 to 6 in the result, is this a mistake?

Comment: uhm no it's not a mistake, those are values calculated from an Excel file, they're all supposed to be different.

Comment: @user1734229: You misunderstand. Your input `1225` dict does not match your output `1225` dict; the value for `B` in the output was changed.

Comment: AAAAH yes sorry it was a mistake! Thanks for pointing it out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `continue` statement will skip the rest of the code in the loop and start a new iteration. There is no reason to use it here - you should remove it so that the `sum += celldict[num][key]` line is actually executed.

You can also write this whole thing more simply:

```
for d in celldict.values():
    d['AB'] = d.get('A',0) + d.get('B',0)
```

Comment: Oh it's that simple! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

It'll be much simpler to use a quick generator loop and the `sum()` function:

```
sumkey = ''.join(a)
for num in celldict:
    num[sumkey] = sum(num.get(k, 0) for k in a)
```

This solution is generic, you can add extra keys to `a` and it'll continue to work.

Comment: Thank you, I am new to Python and I still don't know all the functions it provides. I've already written this script in Perl, it works fine but it's great to see that Python is much more simple to read and to write. I think I'll stick with Python.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing after continue will run in the else block

Answer (score 0):

A short solution would be this:

```
def sum_keys(d, keys=["A","B"]):
    #iterate over all the dictionaries in d
    for subdict in d.values():
        #check that all required keys are in the dict
        if not all(k in subdict for k in keys): continue
        #create the sum and assign it
        subdict[''.join(keys)] = sum(subdict[k] for k in keys)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [29]: for item in celldict:
   ....:     if celldict[item].has_key('A') and celldict[item].has_key('B'):
   ....:         celldict[item]['AB'] = celldict[item]['A'] + celldict[item]['B']
   ....:

In [30]: celldict
Out[30]:
{1224: {'A': 6, 'AB': 10, 'B': 4, 'C': 5},
 1225: {'A': 6, 'AB': 12, 'B': 6, 'C': 5}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
celldict = {1224:{'A': 6, 'B': 4, 'C': 5}, 1225: {'A': 6, 'B': 4, 'C': 5}}
count_keys = ["A","B"]
counted_key = "AB"

for item in celldict.values():
    item[counted_key] = 0

    for key in count_keys:
        item[counted_key] += item[key]

print(celldict)
```